# separate debug-info files in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, debugging, gdb, elf

In GNU/Linux, there are `debug-link` and `build-id` sections in ELF files which shows separate debug-info files name or CRC32 [https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html].
There are also debug packets (e.g. nginx-debug) which can be installed by `yum` or `apt`.

I am new to FreeBSD and did not find such debug sections in ELF files or debug-packets. Is there separate debug-info files in FreeBSD?